# New tag synonym for Cyanogenmod tag

Tags: discussion

It's been a while since Cyanogenmod released its Lollipop based ROMs with the title CM12. However, the tag synonym for [cyanogenmod](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cyanogenmod) are still [cm11](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cm11) and [cyanogenmod11](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cyanogenmod11). Shouldn't there be a new tag synonym named [cm12](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cm12) by now?

I've two questions ([1](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/109147/96277), [2](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/106660/96277)) that requires specifically the tag [cm12](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cm12) over tag [cyanogenmod](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cyanogenmod) as an example. Also, if you see [new questions](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/cyanogenmod/new) under [cyanogenmod](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cyanogenmod) you'll notice a lot of them at first page related to CM12 specifically.

Comment: Hmm, synonymizing only one version is a bad idea, not sure why we did that.  But we should probably have a generic tag and then separate tags for versions with enough questions, there's definitely enough for that.  I've undone the synonyms for the moment.

Comment: @MatthewRead: [Should we have version-specific CyanogenMod tags?](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/questions/1715/should-we-have-version-specific-cyanogenmod-tags) was where this originally came up

Comment: @eldarerathis Thank you very much for the link. Now I see how [tag:cm11] tag  came into existence. // Both Moderators:  So what would be next now? I still feel the need for [tag:cm12] tag since while searching "OnePlus One/ S5 and CM12" I don't want any CM 11 or any other  Cyanogenmod results (you get the point).

Comment: @eldarerathis Thanks.  I think I may have misjudged how much a agreement there was in those comments.  Firelord, I would suggest that we retag questions with `cyanogenmod-11` and `cyanogenmod-12` where appropriate.  We can probably leave plain-jane `cyanogenmod` for legacy versions?  And for general questions about CM.